# How to have a navigation within a modal with react-native-router-flux

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need to have a navigation within a modal in my react-native application

Using the new version of `react-native-router-flux`, it doesn't seem to be possible to do that. I can create a vertical animation to display the next scene, which is not the same as having a modal on top of a scene.

```
    <Scene key="login" direction="vertical">
        <Scene key="loginModal" component={Login} schema="modal" title="Login"/>
        <Scene key="loginModal2" hideNavBar={true} component={Login2} title="Login2"/>
    </Scene>
```

In my case, I need my modal to have a transparent color background, so I would be able to see the scene behind the modal.

The only way for me to do that would be to use the component `<Modal>` from react-native and to have a navigation in it, but it doesn't seem there is a way to define something like this in the `Router`.

What I would need is more something like this:

```
{/* LoginModal would be a wrapper which can render children */}
<Scene key="login" component={LoginModal}>
    <Scene key="loginModal" component={Login} title="Login"/>
    <Scene key="loginModal2" hideNavBar={true} component={Login2} title="Login2" panHandlers={null} duration={1}/>
</Scene>
```

Then, in `LoginModal` would be rendering something like this:

```
render(){
    return (
        <Modal animated={true} transparent={true} visible={true}>
            {/* Render the scene that needs to be rendered,
                including the navigation bar */}
            {this.props.children} 
        </Modal>
    );
```

Is there a way I could accomplish this? Or do you know any better way to have a similar route system for react-native?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you stick with react native router flux?

Comment: I didn't, I'm using the native Navigator component.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was going to do, too.