# react-native-router-flux popping to parent scene or popping multiple scenes

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

I need to have navigation *within* a modal in my react-native app.

The user opens the modal to perform a specific task, and upon completing it (or canceling) is returned to the screen they were on when they opened the modal to start the task.

I like the redux pattern and am trying to use redux for this app. So far so good, but this modal problem has me stuck.

I have tried several approaches via `Navigator` and other libraries and have arrived at `react-native-router-flux` as the best navigation option for use with redux.  However, after several different attempts and a lot of digging in the docs, I'm stuck trying to make this work. I have stepped back and asked if there is another user-flow that would solve this problem, but I really can't think of any.

To explain in more detail, take a look at the following:

```
<RouterWithRedux>
    <Scene key={routerActions.APP_HOME} component={Home} hideNavBar={true}/>
    <Scene key={routerActions.ADD_TODO_MODAL__ROOT} direction="vertical">
        <Scene key={routerActions.ADD_TODO_MODAL__TODO_DETAIL} component={ItemLibrary} title="Details" initial={true}/>
        <Scene key={routerActions.ADD_TODO_MODAL__TODO_DATE_PICKER} component={ItemLibrary} title="Select Due Date"/>
        <Scene key={routerActions.ADD_TODO_MODAL__TODO_REVIEW} component={ItemEditor} title="Review"/>
    </Scene>
</RouterWithRedux>
```

When the user, sitting on `ADD_TODO_MODAL__TODO_REVIEW`, has reviewed their Todo and saves it, the whole modal should close (as in, the whole group of scenes nested in `ADD_TODO_MODAL__ROOT`, dismissing vertically as a whole just like canceling a react-native `Modal` object), and should put the user back on `APP_HOME`.

If I simply try pushing `APP_HOME`, it comes in from the side on top of the old view, and is not the behavior the user is expecting. Besides that, I'm just building up the navigation stack and never popping anything off.

I've tried calling `Actions.pop()` a few times back to back, but that seems like a major hack. Not to mention that while you end up back on `APP_HOME` , the animations go a bit crazy as it tries to deal with popping the first couple of scenes.

I tried using `Switch` but may have been using it wrongly. The docs and examples are few, and from what I could see it doesn't apply to non-tabbed navigation. Am I wrong? Can you give me a simple example using `Switch` that does the flow I'm talking about?

And in general, does anyone have experience building this kind of user flow using `react-native-router-flux`?  I would really like to use redux here, but maybe I should abandon my hopes for using redux in this way and try a flux approach with Navigator? I'm open to other library suggestions as well.

Thanks for looking!

Comment: @alexmngn - I noticed that you have a similar post as this from April [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36464201/how-to-have-a-navigation-within-a-modal-with-react-native-router-flux). Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Did you stick with it? I'm about to get rid of it entirely.

Comment: @Renato I got rid of it entirely.  If it would help you I will post what I did. I should probably do that anyway...

Comment: I plan on doing the same in the next sprint, but if you wouldn't mind posting it, it'll be a good guidance and the community might enjoy ;-)